# TFS checkin without workspace

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I've done some research, but I can't seem to find the answer in the Microsoft docs. I was wondering if someone with TFS experience could let me know if it's possible to checkin a file without creating a workspace through the TF command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible.

A few alternatives:

#### You could create a very small workspace mapping:

For example:

`$/TFS/Project/Folder/SubFolder/` mapping to `C:\Work\`.

#### Perform a non-recursive "get" on just the file you want to edit.

For example:

Map `$/TFS` to `C:\Code\` and then just do a get (either in VS or "tf get $/Whatever") on the file you want.

#### Web Access

If you have TFS 2015, there is "Quick Code Editing" that allows you to edit via the web interface, more [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-dec-17-vso).

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. You always need a workspace mapping.

You could create a small batch file which does the steps required, or create a small C# console app.