# Check-in in memory file to Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: c#, tfs

I need help with checking in the files to Team Foundation Server 2015. Is there any opportunity to create in memory file and then just add it to existing project in TFS?

P.S. I tried to do as described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/ but I don`t have an ability to use local files.

Comment: Why can't you use local files?

Comment: Because file will be created dynamically in webservice without ability to Map folder to TFS folder

Comment: I don't think you can use the technique in that linked post without a workspace, and I don't see how you can have a workspace without files. You could though spin up a temporary workspace in your webservice and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you just want to check in a file to TFS without workspace, this is not possible. You **always need a workspace mapping**.

Just as *stuartd* suggested in the comment, you should dynamically create a workspace before checking in. Similar question for your reference: [TFS checkin without workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127760/tfs-checkin-without-workspace)